# How to process gradients with a Dimension size of None

Tags: tensorflow

Using AdamOptimizer, when I get the gradients of a 2d variable, the second dimension's size ends up being None, while the first dimension is the same size as the variable's first dimension.  This makes it difficult to process the gradients, since a size of None isn't compatible with other sizes for most functions.  When I get the gradients of a 1d variable, the gradient's dimension size is the same as the variable's.  I haven't tried variables with more than 2 dimensions.

Is this a bug?  Is there a way to specify what the size of the gradient should be through the compute_gradients function?  Is there a way to process the gradient that gets around the size None issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:** It shouldn't matter, and  you can process the gradients using the [`tf.train.AdamOptimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/train.html#AdamOptimizer) as normal. If you are seeing shape-related errors, this most likely arises from one of the known dimensions not matching.

The presence of `None` in a gradient tensor's [shape](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/framework.html#TensorShape) simply means that the size in that dimension could not be statically inferred. This is not necessarily a bug: the shapes of many operators depend on their data inputs, and the TensorFlow Python front-end uses a simple heuristic (i.e., only compute a limited set of ops with constant inputs) to decide what data inputs to evaluate. Almost all of the TensorFlow ops—excluding some image processing ops—will work on inputs whose shape is unknown (or only partially known), and perform checks at runtime instead.

The main way to process gradients is using [`Optimizer.apply_gradients()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.compute_gradients), which defers shape checking to the [shape function for the `ApplyAdam` operator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a27d844e05447e65aa279ae5269a2d75590f46f6/tensorflow/python/training/training_ops.py#L61). This shape function asserts that the variable and gradient have the same shape, but the [`TensorShape.merge_with()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/framework.html#TensorShape.merge_with) method allows false positives in the presence of `None` in either of the shapes.

Finally, if you need to process the gradients at graph construction time, and your processing somehow depends on the gradients having known shapes, you can always use the [`Tensor.set_shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor.set_shape) method to copy the shape of the variable to the shape of the gradient, as these must be equivalent:

```
var = tf.Variable(...)
loss = ...
grad = tf.gradients(loss, [var])[0]

# `grad` and `var` must have the same shape.
grad.set_shape(var.get_shape())
```